# getting a part of the output from a sed command

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have this Command :

```
cat -n file.log | grep "Start new test" | tail -1 |  cut -f 1 |  xargs -I % sed -n %',$s/is not alive/&/p' file.log
```

That gives the output of the whole line :

```
Jan 19 23:20:33 s_localhost@file platMgt.xbin[3260]: blade 10 is not alive
Jan 19 23:20:33 s_localhost@file platMgt.xbin[3260]: blade 11 is not alive
```

how can I modify it to get the last part only :
blade 11 is not alive

can I modify that in a way to display :

```
Error:blade 11 is not alive ?
```

Thank you for your response

Comment: the Grep is returning a line number, the sed is searching for the line that contains the string : is not alve, it prints the whole line, I was trying to make it only print a specific part of the line ,it is printing :

Jan 19 23:20:33 s_localhost@file platMgt.xbin[3260]: blade 10 is not alive

I want it only to print the :

blade 10 is not alive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cut to delimit it on the colons and then add the error message:

```
cat -n file.log | grep "Start new test" | tail -1 |  cut -f 1 |  xargs -I % sed -n %',$s/is not alive/&/p' file.log | cut -d: -f 4 | xargs -I % echo Error: %
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the last part after colon awk is better tool:

```
s='Jan 19 23:20:33 s_localhost@file platMgt.xbin[3260]: blade 10 is not alive'
awk -F':' '{print "Error:" $NF}' <<< "$s"
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
 blade 10 is not alive
```

**EDIT:** WIth your piped commands you can combine it as:

```
grep "Start new test" file.log|tail -1|awk -F':' '{print "Error:" $NF}'
```

PS: Though this whole thing is possible in awk itself.

Comment: can you combine the AWK with the command I posted in the question ?

Comment: +1, but to address the heart of the OP's question you should use `awk -F':' '{print "Error:" $NF}'`. Your answer strikes me as the simplest - I think the only reason the OP didn't go for it is because you didn't put together the full command for him.

Comment: Yes I could have provided full path but there was very little info about all those piped commands in question and I just didn't feel comfortable of adding something untested in my answer. OP can just replace last sed with this awk to get desired output. But as I noted that most of the piped commands can be eliminated by awk itself.

Answer (score 0):

The following obtains the the last ":" separated field with a sed command,

```
cat text.txt | sed 's/^.*: \([^:]*$\)/\1/g'
```